# What do the new berries in Pokémon Go do?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the latest update, [0.57.2 for Android and 1.27.2 for iOS](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-021617), Niantic not only released Generation 2 Pokémon, they released new berries as well.

> Pokémon GO is in the process of being updated to version 0.57.2 for Android and 1.27.2 for iOS devices. Below are some release notes and comments from our development team.
>
> ...
>
> Added two new Berries.
>
> ...

What do these new berries do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.polygon.com/2017/2/15/14619130/pokemon-go-new-pokemon-gen-two):

> The Nanab Berry and Pinap Berry are the two new berry items in trainers’ arsenals. The Nanab Berry will slow Pokemon down so it’s less likely for them to run off, while Pinap Berries help players collect twice as much candy upon a successful catch.

It looks like the Nanab berry slows down pokemon to prevent them from escaping, and Pinap berry helps you to gain twice as much candy when you catch a pokemon.

Comment: I can see people abusing the Pinap berry during special events where they already get additional candies

Comment: This isn't exactly what the help descriptions in the game say. Specifically, it says the nanab berry calms them so they don't move around as much, or something like that.

Comment: The Pinap Berry isn't twice as much - it's two extra candies. That is, you get 3 for a normal catch... but 5 if you catch the Pokemon on the throw immediately after using the Pinap.

Comment: @TimMalone are you sure? Multiple sources state otherwise, such as [this one](http://heavy.com/games/2017/02/pokemon-go-what-are-nanab-berries-pinap-new-items-where-to-get-pokestop/), [this one](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/berry/) and the one in my answer.

Comment: @TimmyJim I can confirm I received double candy

Comment: Can you use 2 berries at once?

Comment: @Batophobia that may be better suited for a separate question if you can elaborate some on it :)

Comment: @TimmyJim It would be a relatively simple thing to test, I just don't have multiple types of berries or access to the game at the moment.

Comment: @Batophobia and I don't even play the game so I can't test it either!

Comment: @TimmyJim [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300852/42984) suggests the answer is no, you can only use 1 berry at a time.

Comment: @TimmyJim That's weird... it definitely is only giving me 2 extra, many times! :/ And yes, you can only use one Berry at a time.