# What exactly are the "new encounter mechanics"?

Tags: pokemon-go

The patch notes for Pokémon Go version 0.57.2 for Android and 1.27.2 for iOS devices are as follows:

- Over 80 additional Pokémon originally discovered in the Johto region can be caught.
- Gender-specific variations of select Pokémon can be caught.
- ***Added new encounter mechanics.***
- Added Poké Ball and Berry selection carousels to the encounter screen.
- Added two new Berries.
- Added new avatar outfit and accessory options.
- Added new night-mode map and encounter music.
- Added bonus Candies for catching Evolved Pokémon.
- Implemented Apple Watch connection stability improvement.
- Various bug fixes.
- Minor text fixes.

What exactly are the new encounter mechanics?

Comment: I think the mechanics are how they annoy you when trying to capture. I noticed some pokemon will now sway side to side instead of just sitting there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this datamine of the most recent APK](https://thesilphroad.com/news/pokemon-go-apk-v057-2-gen-2-evolution-items), there are a couple mechanical changes to encounters.

> Code has appeared fleshing out the CRITICAL CATCH mechanic which first appeared in the previous APK but has not been implemented. The following components now appear:
>
> - CRITICALSHAKE
> - CRITICALCLICK
> - CATCHSUCCESSCRITICAL

I can not confirm whether these have actually been implemented or not yet, but according to this [Silph Road reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5uiwpu/gen_2_release_centralized_facts/), they have been:

> Critical catches have been implemented. You know it's a critical catch when the ball immediately drops on the ground after hitting the Pokémon and has 4 rays of light leaving upwards in a zig zag motion.

Additionally, as @Rapitor has mentioned in the comments on the question and as I have personally witnessed already, Pokémon now move in more directions than up to mess up your throws. They can move side-to-side (which unfortunately makes their CP go off-screen if you have AR-mode turned off). From that same datamine, it seems there are other states that they can be in:

> It appears the way Pokémon interact during wild encounters has been upgraded. There are now several movement types at play rather than just 'wait', 'jump,' and 'attack':
>
> - JUMPMOVEMENTSTATE
> - ELECTRICMOVEMENTSTATE
> - PSYCHICMOVEMENTSTATE
> - SETUPHOVERMOVEMENTNODES
> - SETUPFLYINGMOVEMENTNODES

According to the same Reddit thread as above that confirmed critical captures, it appears that different Pokémon tend to move in different patterns (probably explains the naming conventions chosen):

> Pokémon move in new ways during the catch sequence. Ledyba will move in a "V" motion, while Qwilfish will move sideways form left to right, with their catch circles following them. Other users in this same thread also report new movements for gen 1 Pokémon like Venonat or Abra.

Another change worth mentioning is that you are still only able to use a single berry at a time during a Pokémon encounter, as mentioned in the (same) Reddit thread:

> You can only use 1 berry at a time on a Pokémon. So no, you can't use a razz + a nanab on a Pokémon. The active berry is used as an icon on the Pokémon. Once the icon disappear, on a failed catch attempt, you can use an another berry.