# What can affect a Pokemon's ability to be captured?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've noticed that when capturing Pokemon, capture rates are all over the shop. Regardless of CP, sometimes Pokemon will simply refuse to be captured, though they'll stick around for you to try, try, try again, and waste all your balls and berries. Others will get in the ball the first time, on a terrible throw, even though they have a relatively high CP.

Other Pokemon will refuse to sit still; constantly attacking or jumping, and some will immediately flee after the first capture attempt.

I understand there are things at play in regards to badges that can affect capture rates, but my focus is on Pokemon behaviour, in regards to the 3 IV stats - Attack, Defense, and Stamina.

Is there any correlation here? If not, what does affect it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. A 0,0,0 Pokemon has the same capture rate as a 15,15,15 Pokemon of the same level and species.

The capture chance of a throw depends on the following:

- The species of the Pokemon
- The level of the Pokemon encountered (**not its CP**- more on that below)
- The ball used (better balls have a higher catch rate)
- If a golden razz berry, razz berry or silver pinap berry was used
- The throw bonus (good/great/excellent throw)
- Curveball bonus
- Medal bonus (the player receives a bonus if they have a medal for catching many pokemon of the same type)

The IVs of the pokemon are not considered here. Nor is CP (which is affected by IVs). Higher CP pokemon are generally harder to catch, but this is because they are a higher level, not directly because their CP is higher.

Source: https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics