# How many extra Candies does Pinap Berry grant?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've recently started using Pinap Berries from time to time and have experienced inconsistent results.

I've not yet used any on evolved Pokemon yet, but the Basic Pokemon I used them on gave me either 5 or 6 total candies. All of them have evolutions, though I didn't pay attention to whether the 5 and 6 were split between 1-stage and 2-stage evolutions.

So, how many (extra or total) candies does Pinap Berry grant, depending on which factors?

Comment: 5 candy on pinap berry [might be a bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ukc02/bug_pinap_berry_shows_one_less_candy_earnt_on_the/)

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but it answers your question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300805/what-do-the-new-berries-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go-do

Comment: @TimmyJim Well, it was intended to clarify the mechanics because based on the in-game display, it doesn't double the Candy. Although now that we know it's just a visual bug, it kinda does boil down to a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does exactly grant the double amount of candy for each stage of evolution. Don't bother the incorrect report of 5, 9, or 19 candies. They are being added to your candy total as 6 for stage 1 pokemon (eg. Pidgey), 10 for stage 2 pokemon (eg. Pidgeotto), and 20 for stage 3 pokemon (eg. Pidgeot) when captured using Pinap Berry.

Tested and verified by myself.

Screenshots added below illustrating the candy count problem.

[image: Screenshot (incorrectly) showing 5 candies added.]
[image: Screenshot showing the 6 candies added after hitting OK.]

Comment: I don't doubt this answer, but if this is correct, I can understand the confusion. When I caught a Totodile yesterday using a pinap, the *catch screen* showed the 3 standard candies for the catch first, had a little animation, and then the candy total went to 5. Unfortunately I don't know how many candies I had previous to the catch to compare the before and after, but just from the post-catch summary, I assumed I got 5 candies **in total**.

Comment: This false calculation of the candy amount will most probably be corrected in an intermediary version release with many other possible bugs.

Comment: i think you are wrong because i am using pinap berry on magicarp and m not getting any extra candie..only 3 no matter what pokemon is..

Comment: I was catching pokemon yesterday with my brother, he i lvl 24 and got 6 candy when het catched it. I (lvl 27) got 5 candy for catching the same pokemon. (We both didn't transfer it to the professor.) So I would guess the lvl you are is part of it as well.

Comment: This is very confusing because as you catch a Pokemon, you first see 3 candies and then it bumps up to 5 candies. After you hit okay it will show +6 candies in the upper right-hand corner of the screen.

Comment: @Montag451 I know I'm a bit late to the party, but Niantic confirmed this (is/was?) a typographical error on their [Known Issues](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958208-Known-Issues) page

Answer (score 0):

Pinap berries grant 2 times the amount of candy it would originally give if it doesn't it's probably just an animation error